# I need help finding integral of $(x^2-2x+3)/(x^2+x-2)$

Tags: integration

I don't know how can I solve this integral of rational function
$$
\int\frac{x^2-2x+3}{x^2+x-2}dx
$$
Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** $$\frac{x^2-2x+3}{x^2+x-2} = 1 +\frac{-3x+5}{x^2+x-2}$$ and $x^2+x-2=(x+2)(x-1)$, can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Using [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html)

as  $x^2+x-2=(x+2)(x-1)$,

$$\frac{x^2-2x+3}{x^2+x-2} =1+\frac A{x+2}+\frac B{x-1}$$

$$\implies x^2-2x+3=x^2+x-2+A(x-1)+B(x+2)$$

Compare the constants and the coefficients $x,x^2$ to find $A,B$

Now, we know $\displaystyle \int\frac{dx}{x+a}=\ln|x+a|+C$